# Select Arduino from comports in python

Tags: python, arduino

I am trying to select Arduino from connected USB devices on linux, when I am using lsusb to list USB devices there is output with correct device name/description with Arduino (HL-340) string.

When I am using script below, the description for connected Arduino is 'None'

```
import warnings
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports

arduino_ports = [
    p.device
    for p in serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
    if 'Arduino' in p.description or 'HL-340' in p.description
]
if not arduino_ports:
    raise IOError("No Arduino found")
if len(arduino_ports) > 1:
    warnings.warn('Multiple Arduinos found - using the first')

ser = serial.Serial(arduino_ports[0])
```

I have check all objects from https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools.html#serial.tools.list_ports.ListPortInfo
to check if there is Arduino string to select correct USB device but nothing give out good name/description like lsusb

for example,
lsusb output with my arduino is
'Bus 004 Device 005: ID 1a86:7523 QinHeng Electronics HL-340 USB-Serial adapter'
and for serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
description is None and product is USB2.0-Ser!

Does it possible to set Arduino name/description when compiling script in Arduino IDE or what is the better way to select Arduino device using python script.

Answer (score 1):

On my system with a single Arduino Uno connected, the values returned by `serial.tools.list_ports.comports()` look like this:

```
>>> print('\n'.join(str(info) for info in [[x.manufacturer, x.product, x.serial_number, x.description]  for x in serial.tools.list_ports.comports()]))
[None, None, None, 'n/a']
[None, None, None, 'ttyS0']
['Arduino (www.arduino.cc)', None, '853343330323512021D1', 'ttyACM0']
```

So the only attribute that contains the string `Arduino` is the `manufacturer` attribute.

If I rewrite your code like this:

```
import warnings
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports

arduino_ports = [
    p.device
    for p in serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
    if p.manufacturer and 'Arduino' in p.manufacturer
]
if not arduino_ports:
    raise IOError("No Arduino found")
if len(arduino_ports) > 1:
    warnings.warn('Multiple Arduinos found - using the first')

print('using port', arduino_ports[0])
ser = serial.Serial(arduino_ports[0])
```

The it correctly detects my Uno:

```
$ python listunos.py
using port /dev/ttyACM0
```

A complete dump of the values for the Arduino looks like:

```
>>> import serial.tools.list_ports
>>> import.json
>>> for dev in serial.tools.list_ports.comports():
...     print(json.dumps(vars(dev), indent=2))
{
  "device": "/dev/ttyACM0",
  "name": "ttyACM0",
  "description": "ttyACM0",
  "hwid": "USB VID:PID=2341:0043 SER=853343330323512021D1 LOCATION=1-8:1.0",
  "vid": 9025,
  "pid": 67,
  "serial_number": "853343330323512021D1",
  "location": "1-8:1.0",
  "manufacturer": "Arduino (www.arduino.cc)",
  "product": null,
  "interface": null,
  "usb_device_path": "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8",
  "device_path": "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0",
  "subsystem": "usb",
  "usb_interface_path": "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0"
}
```

Comment: for me, manufacturer also return None (on linux), do you have another solution to change it on Arduino side? On windows my output:

manufacturer wch.cn,
device COM8,
name COM8,
description USB-SERIAL CH340 (COM8),
hwid USB VID:PID=1A86:7523 SER= LOCATION=1-9,
vid 6790,
pid 29987,
serial_number,
location 1-9,
product None,
interface None

Comment: If you run the example at the bottom of my answer (with the `json.dumps`), do any of the fields contain `Arduino`? Does that change if you run it as `root` (i.e., `sudo python ...`)?

Comment: No, it does not contain Arduino, output: https://i.imgur.com/AwccTYM.jpeg
there is no difference between using regular user or root